# Using dedicated thread to update particles degrades performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-oriented-design

I have a boids simulation using data oriented design and with out any threading code it runs at 30 fps. I decided to improve performance using dedicated threads to update the boids but the performance went from 30 fps to 10 fps. The data is global so it can be accessed by any thread

At the beginning I thought it was a problem of false sharing so I tried to run the update code just with one thread but I still have low fps compared with the non threaded version. Worth to mention that the main thread only access the data to read (render) and never writes to it. Sorry if is to much code but I tried to extract the most significant part of it so you can have an idea how it works.

```
// Structures of arrays for the boids
struct SActorsData
{
    SColor*     Color;
    SVector3*   Position;
    SVector3*   Scale;
    Mesh**      MeshPtr;
};

struct SBoidsData
{
    SVector3*       Velocity;
    float*          Radius;
    .
    .
    .
};


std::vector<bool> WorkersSemaphore;
std::vector<std::thread> Workers;
std::vector<CActor*> Actors;
SActorsData ActorsData;
SBoidsData BoidsData;


struct CActor
{
   // points to the index corresponding to the data of this actor
   uint32_t ActorIdx;


   Update()
   {
        .
        .
        .
       ActorsData.Position[ActorIdx] = ActorsData.Position[ActorIdx] +  BoidsData.Velocity[ActorIdx] * DeltaTime;      
   }
};


void WorkerUpdate(uint32_t ThreadIdx, uint32_t ActorsStartIdx, uint32_t ActorsEndIdx)
{
    while (bIsAppRunning)
    {
        if (WorkersSemaphore[ThreadIdx])
        {
            for (uint32_t i = ActorsStartIdx; i < ActorsEndIdx; ++i)
            {
                Actors[i]->Update();
            }

            WorkersSemaphore[ThreadIdx] = false;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
        // Code sample on how I allocate memory for each field
    uint16_t BoidsAdditionalBuffer = 100;
    BoidsData.Velocity  = new SVector3[InitialBoidsCount + BoidsAdditionalBuffer];

    .
    .
    .
    // Create the worker threads
    int32_t ChunkSize = Actors.size() / NumWorkers;
    int32_t Reminder = Actors.size() - ChunkSize * NumWorkers;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < NumWorkers; ++i)
    {
        uint32_t ActorsStartIdx = i * ChunkSize;
        uint32_t ActorsEndIdx = i * ChunkSize + ChunkSize;

        WorkersSemaphore.push_back(false);
        Workers.push_back(std::move(std::thread(WorkerUpdate, i, ActorsStartIdx, ActorsEndIdx)));
    }

    while (bIsAppRunning)
    {
        // Update the semaphores to true so worker threads can update
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < WorkersSemaphore.size(); ++i)
        {
            WorkersSemaphore[i] = true;
        }

        // Wait until worker threads have completed the update
        while (true)
        {
            bool bUpdateDone = true;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < WorkersSemaphore.size(); ++i)
            {
                bUpdateDone &= !WorkersSemaphore[i];
            }

            if (bUpdateDone)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Render();
    }
}
```

As I mention if I run this code with just one worker thread the performance goes to the trash. I don't really know what could be.

Comment: Not an answer, but `WorkersSemaphore[ThreadIdx] = false;` isn't threadsafe. `std::vector<bool>` could be optimized to bit array. I'd say it's better to use an atomic counter to count how many chunks you have to update. Also, could you try to run workers functions in the main loop to make sure that you didn't introduce regression during modification?

Comment: Can you please explain your self on why WorkersSemaphore is not thread safe? Is an array and each thread will only access the data in its corresponding index. And yes! I ran the test with out threads using the worker function in the loop with an expected performance of 30 FPS.

Comment: As I said - `std::vector<bool>` could be optimized to a bit array. In this case, each bool would be one bit and assignment won't be atomic. As for performance, it's hard to tell from this code. With a runnable example, it'd be easier.